# SQL to get these unique rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Have a table, and need to output only certain rows.  Here is the example:

Table:

```
ID  Pacct   Sacct
----------------------
10  12  12
9   13  12
12  14  12
4   15  16
5   16  15
6   17  18
7   19  18
```

Need to select rows where Pacct <> Sacct whenever there also exists rows where Pacct = Sacct

So, for the table above, the output I am looking for will be:

```
ID  PAcct   Sacct
--------------------------
9   13  12
12  14  12
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm confused. `pacct <> sacct` AND `pacct = sacct` is a contradiction

Comment: He's saying that he only wants to return a result in the case that there are rows that exist in the entire table that satisfy pacct = sacct. So, `SELECT * FROM table WHERE pacct <> sacct` only if `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE pacct = sacct` > 0

Comment: RDBMS is SQL Server 2008.

Comment: @crush, Why aren't the last four rows selected then?

Comment: @user1967701 According to that, the only row that should be excluded is `ID = 10`

Comment: this is a real head scratcher.

Comment: It is not a contradiction, if you look in the table I gave -- The first 3 rows -- THe first row has both the columns the same, the next two rows have unequal columns.  My goal is to oupt put these unequal columns as long as there is one row where both the columns are equal.  Thanks.

Comment: i see what you are doing. what if the 3 12's where in pacct, and not sacct. do you need that too?

Comment: You should use SQL fiddle.

Comment: @user1967701 update your question with that then

Comment: -1, you need to clarify why the last three rows aren't being returned.

Comment: @AbeMiessler  Because there are no records where both PACCT and SACCT are equal to 16, 17, or 19.  The bigger question is why is the record with id 12 being returned as I see no rows where PACCT and SACCT are both 14.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying, but the wording of the question needs to be clarified... it's not whenever _any_ row exists where paact = saact (because then, as Abe Miessler pointed out, it would return all the rows except ID 10, since 12 = 12.) I'm guessing you mean all the rows with a value of sacct such that a row exists where sacct = pacct?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want pairs of `pacct` and `sacct` where they are different and where `sacct` in not in the list of `paccts` where the two are the same:

```
select *
from t
where pacct <> s.acct and
      s.acct in (select t2.pacct from t t2 and t2.sacct = t2.pacct)
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you're looking for something along these lines. But I'm not sure.

```
select *
from Table1 
inner join 
  (select D, Pacct, Sacct
   from Table1
   where Pacct = Sacct ) p_eq_s
on Table1.Pacct = p_eq_s.Sacct
or Table1.Pacct = p_eq_s.Pacct
or Table1.Sacct = p_eq_s.Sacct
or Table1.Sacct = p_eq_s.Pacct
where Table1.Pacct <> Table1.Sacct
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.PAcct, t1.Sacct
FROM MyTable t1
INNER JOIN MyTable t2
ON t2.ID <> t1.ID AND t2.PAcct = t1.PAcct
WHERE t1.PAcct <> t1.Sacct
AND t2.PAcct = t2.Sacct
```

Please note that this relies on PAcct and Sacct not being nullable (or the default SQL Server settings regarding null equality comparisons being changed). If they are nullable, the `WHERE t1.PAcct <> t1.Sacct` clause must be changed to account for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select * from table x1
where Pacct <> Sacct 
and exists (select 1 from table x2 
             where x2.Pacct = x2.Sacct and 
                  (x1.Pacct = x2.Pacct or 
                   x1.Sacct = x2.Sacct))
```

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/67f54/2)

Answer (score -1):

you should try something like:

```
SELECT * FROM dump WHERE (PAcct - Sacct = 0);
```